# Cannot load dependencies of stack [segway_rmp]: segway_rmp

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I just followed the instructions in ROS wiki website http://www.ros.org/wiki/segway_rmp to install segway_rmp in my computer.

But it came with the following problem:

Stack: segway_rmp
Cannot load dependencies of stack [segway_rmp]: segway_rmp
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/lilimeng/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot
ROS path [2]=/home/lilimeng/fuerte_workspace/sandbox
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [4]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [5]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [6]=/home/lilimeng/ros_workspace

So what's the problem? Your help is highly appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39705/cannot-load-dependencies-of-stack-%5Bsegway_rmp%5D:-segway_rmp/) by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 286 on 2012-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just add the segway_rmp in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

---

Originally posted by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) with karma: 286 on 2012-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0